# How to reintegrate topic branches after a squash and merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I normally fully embrace merges in git but I have recently started working on a repository where the strategy to merge topic branches into master has been to squash them into a single commit.

I just discovered that this causes utter chaos when trying to reintegrate a second topic branch which was based on the first.

Let's say I have:

```
A-I'          master
 \
  B-C-E-G-I   topicA
     \   \
      D-F-H-J topicB
```

Where `I'` is the squashed merge from `topicA` to `master`.

If I merge `master` into `topicB` then there are a lot of conflicts. Using a merge tool is useless as LOCAL would include changes from `ABCDEFGHJ`, REMOTE will be `ABCEGI` and BASE is `A`. Trying to see the differences `I` vs `DFHJ` can be really difficult. If I give up on the merge tool and just diff LOCAL and REMOTE then the changes are far more obvious but I have to manually resolve all the conflicts.

If I rebase `topicB` on `master` then it gets even stranger as various files changed between `B` and `I` on `topicA` and so reapplying commits `ABCDFJ` onto `I'` produces nonsense.

How do I get `I'` into `topicB`?

Is there a better way to integrate topic branches which would avoid this in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lesser evil turned out to be:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master topicA topicB
```

I didn't pay too much attention at which commits were applied but I'm guessing merge commits (`H`) were lost.

As for avoiding this it seems like merging a topic branch is asking for trouble if that topic branch is going to be squash merged since that is effectively rewriting the history for an upstream branch which is well known to be a bad idea.

I'd love to hear how others solve this since it seems with the FUD around merging people tend to favour rebasing as the "simpler" workflow.

---

Another variation to this which I have found to be very useful is:

```
git rebase -i -r --onto origin/master topicA topicB
```

This will start an interactive rebase and show you which branch commits were made on. This makes it very easy to remove any commit which was made on `topicA`. Without this those commits get replayed onto `master` which can cause all kinds of conflicts since those changes are already there.

Comment: That particular rebase copies commits `J`, `F`, and `D`: the three non-merge commits that are reachable from `topicB` / commit `J` that are not also reachable from `topicA` / commit `I`. There's nothing wrong with this approach: if it moves smoothly for you and makes no problems for anyone else, it's a good way to go.